# Why doesn't span work with Foundation input-box. Icon and foundation input-box on the same line

Tags: css, zurb-foundation, inline, inputbox

Why is it that the input box always pushes other elements to the next line(Or in some cases the input box pushes itself to the next line, to occupy 100% space)

I want to show an icon before the input box.
______
|  icon  |            --------input box--------
|_____ |     |---------------------------|

I tried the below code, but for some reason, `<span>` doesn't seem to work at all.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="medium-12 columns">
        <span>
        </span>
            <i class="fi-page-edit"></i>
        <span>
            <input type="number" id="test"/>
        </span> 
    </div>
</div>
```

In the above case the "icon" and the "input box" never stay in the same line, the input box pushes itself to the next line.

Why is it so?

Here's a JS fiddle example of a similar case: [Foundation- Input box and span tag](http://jsfiddle.net/anish_nair/eqaqqfaa/)

P.S. I am trying to avoid putting the icon and the input-box in `column` like this

```
<div class="medium-1 columns">
    icon
</div>
<div class="medium-11 columns">
    <input type="number"/>
</div>
```

Is there a way to do it using `<span>`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should have given some demo.
You need to give some floating or display property to span.
2 ways:

```
span {
display:inline-block;
vertical-align:middle;
}
```

or

```
span {
 float:left;
}
input{
 float:left;
}
```

If width for input and span if you want to it aligned.

Comment: you can find [http://jsfiddle.net/locateganesh/eqaqqfaa/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/locateganesh/eqaqqfaa/1/). I think this is what you want and it can solve your query.

Comment: I could achieve the same thing using foundation class `row` and `columns`. My question is why doesn't `<span>` for input-box work in foundation, but it works without foundation. I don't want to give css to span. It defeats the purpose of `<span>` tag.